# Merging cells in a column SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want to merge cells in a column like column A or B in the image below:

[image]

That table is a database. All I have now is:

```
$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$wynik = mysqli_query($polaczenie,'SELECT * FROM grafik');
echo "<table cellpadding=7 border=3>";
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"."Dzień"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."Zmiana"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."Stanowisko 1"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."a_1"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."a_2"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."a_3"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."a_4"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."Stanowisko 2"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."b_1"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."b_2"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."b_3"."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"."b_4"."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

while ($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['shift']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stanowisko_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_2']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_3']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_4']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stanowisko_2']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['b_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_2']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_3']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_4']."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
```

It looks like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's the Data and Dzien columns a simple rowspan will do it:

```
while ($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td rowspan='8'>".$row['date']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td rowspan='8'>".$row['shift']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stanowisko_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_2']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_3']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['a_4']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stanowisko_2']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['b_1']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_2']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_3']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['b_4']."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
```